# Showing that there exists a unique $x \in V$ such that $v+3x=w$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to show that there exists a unique $x \in V$ such that $v+3x=w$. ($v,w \in V$ and $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$ and $\mathbb{F} $ can be $\mathbb{R} $ or $\mathbb{C}$).

This is my attempt:

Since $w \in V$, there exists a unique additive inverse, $-w \in V$ such that $w-w=0$.

Then we have: $$ v+3x -w =0.$$

Using the associativity and commutativity properties of vectors, we have:
\begin{equation} \tag{1}
 (v-w)+3x=0.
\end{equation}

Multiplying $(1)$ by $\frac{1}{3} \in \mathbb{F}$, we get:

\begin{equation} \tag{2}
\frac{1}{3} (v-w) +x =0.
\end{equation}

Then equation $(2)$ implies that $x$ is the additive inverse of the vector $\frac{1}{3}(v-w)$ and since additive inverses are unique, $x = -\frac{1}{3}(v-w)$ is unique.

I am not sure whether I have proved what was asked or in general, if the reasoning of each step of the proof valid?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, what's $\mathbb F$?  If it has characteristic $3$, your argument fails (and the claim is false). If it has any other characteristic, you're good.

Comment: @lulu Okay cool. What is a characteristic? ($\mathbb{F} $ is $\mathbb{R} $or $\mathbb{C}$).

Comment: Ah, well if you intended $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, there's no problem, those both have characteristic $0$.  (though you should edit your question to indicate this restriction).  There are other sorts of fields, like the field with $3$ elements.  For that one, there is no $\frac 13$ since $3x=0$ identically.  You can read about the general theory of field (or ring) characteristics [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_(algebra)).

Comment: @lulu okay cool, thank you for your help.